# crear trigger mysql

Tags: sql

Tengo un problema con el siguiente **trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEPORTES_AFTER_INSERT 
AFTER ISERT ON CONTENIDO 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO c_deportes 
(c_id, c_titulo, c_descripcion, c_categoria, c_fecha_entrada, c_contenido, c_imagen, c_nombre_imagen) 
values (new.c_id, new.c_titulo, new.c_descripcion, new.c_categoria, new.c_fecha_entrada, new.c_contenido, new.c_imagen, new.c_nombre_imagen)
```

Está correcto. corresponde a las entradas de un blog. Pero ¿cómo hago para que cada vez que yo registre un **post**, se cargue solamente el post que tiene categoría "DEPORTES" y no todos los post. Por que con ese trigger me esta insertando todos los registros a c_deportes y no quiero eso. se podría establecer una clausula **where?**

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, te falta una clausula **WHERE**, ya que con ella puedes filtrar lo que deseas, que en este caso es solo cargar el post con la categoria **DEPORTES** 
Te quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TRIGGER DEPORTES_AFTER_INSERT 
AFTER ISERT ON CONTENIDO 
FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO c_deportes 
(c_id, c_titulo, c_descripcion, c_categoria, c_fecha_entrada, c_contenido, c_imagen, c_nombre_imagen) 
values (new.c_id, new.c_titulo, new.c_descripcion, new.c_categoria, new.c_fecha_entrada, new.c_contenido, new.c_imagen, new.c_nombre_imagen) WHERE c_categoria = 'DEPORTES'
```